# Can a domain registrar update google's dns server?

Tags: dns

I'm trying to host a small webserver, for personal use, from my computer..

My cheapy domain registrar allows me to specify a DNS, so was wondering if it's possible to specify google's DNS?  Or does google not allow any old registrar to update their 8.8.8.8 records?

Interestingly, my AT&T uverse router does not allow me to change the DNS server settings (dns156r8/dns157r8.sbcglobal.net).. so will the above even work at home? i.e. if a computer is configured to use Google's DNS, but it connects to the internet via a router that hardcodes the ISP's DNS, which one wins out?

Not sure if others have these types of issues.. but the other head-scratcher is what happens when my IP changes? At the moment, I figure I'll manually enter my IP when it changes into the domain registrar's forwarding section. The DNS would update accordingly?

Comment: One thing you should think about is that your agreement with AT&T precludes you from running servers accessible from the Internet from your home network. If you get it to work, you may one day discover you no longer have Internet access because your ISP found out about your breach of the terms of service.

Comment: You might need to do a bit of reading on how DNS works; but for your case, dyndns might solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions seem to be based on numerous misconceptions about how DNS works. But the key thing you're missing is this -- the name server you specify to your registrar must be one that serves the records for your domain. And they have to get those records from somewhere.

Since you have no specific way to tell Google what records to serve for you, and they wouldn't use a public name server to serve your data anyway (because if, for example, it got out of date, they'd be serving wrong data to the public), you would face an unsolvable chicken and egg problem. Google needs to get those records from the DNS infrastructure. And your registrar is pointing that infrastructure at Google. Not good.

Comment: I see.. so the registrar asks for the DNS server to update FROM  (rather than pushing TO).     It's a bit counter-intuitive, at least for me, since isn't the registrar the one that has the control to point a domain to an IP?  What about the scenario of a computer with a different DNS setting than the router it connects to.   Which one wins out?

Comment: @ben The registry has control over the top level domain. So if you register "EXAMPLE.COM", your registrar will tell the registry for "COM" to include the entries for "EXAMPLE.COM" that go in the "COM" zone, which is typically just the correct name server(s) to query for authoritative information about the domain.

Comment: @ben A computer uses whatever nameserver it's configured to use, unless you use specific methods to hijack/redirect its DNS queries, which is not unheard of.

Answer (score 1):

Ron's (very sensible) comments about Terms of Service aside:

You CAN host a server from your Home IP **providing you have a static IP address.** Otherwise you stand a good chance of having your IP change every time your modem re-negotiates it's connection. Which will mean that people will then be looking for your server at the wrong IP.

If you're NOT on a static IP, then you need to look into using a Dynamic IP service to re-map your dynamic IP to either your FQDN (which they usually charge for), or to a FQDN they offer you (often for free).

So you use their FQDN linked to your ever-changing dynamic IP. You then go back to your DNS service and instead of defining an A record to point to a static IP (which you don't have), instead you define a CNAME record which says in effect:

> www.benspage.com points to the same IP being used by ben123.homepc.net